# What is this mipmap artifact?

Tags: unity-game-engine, textures, uv-mapping, mipmaps

There was a weird white line at the edge of my sphere UV when I import texture with mipmap

It disappear when I disable mipmap

What is this?

[image]

This is the texture I used

[image]

Comment: It might be helpful to see your original texture?

Comment: @VPellen OK I have added

Comment: I can't seem to reproduce the problem. It might be an issue with the mesh? It looks like a custom UV sphere rather than the default one.

Comment: @VPellen That's right I make my own custom sphere. The UV was generated as 0 to 1. Was it related to mipmap?

Comment: I think it might be an issue with your UVs rather than just the texture, but it's hard to tell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem lies on the fact that I was generate per pixel UV in shader

https://forum.unity.com/threads/strange-line-artifact-when-doing-1-on-uv-coordinates.544118/

But that's not the problem itself. The point is I need to specified LOD with texture2D sampler LOD when it is a custom per pixel UV. Or else it could has a confusion mipmap between UV 0.99 and 0.01

Comment: To make this work with per-pixel UV coordinates, you have to provide custom uv derivatives (see the Tex2D overload that takes custom dx and dy derivatives https://developer.download.nvidia.com/cg/tex2D.html)